# Add "Print results to PDF" Action to a Grid/List Display in SearchKit?

Tags: searchkit

Would it be possible and if yes than how?

Comment: Just to emphasise, this is about Grids and List Displays.  Custom actions can be added to Tables using `hook_civicrm_searckitTasks()` but that does not apply to Grids/Lists.

Comment: @Aidan thank you! So the answer is  "NO": not via configuration, nor via hooks. Good to know.

Comment: Well, not that I know of but it's developing rapidly. If you don't get a solution here you could create a Gitlab issue suggesting the feature.